# Improving MATLAB logical indexing performance

Tags: performance, matlab, indexing

I'm working on a function that selects all points within a bounding box around a line from a large coordinate set (to speed up a RANSAC fit). I ran the script containing the function last night, and of the total 55k seconds 30k (in 55M calls) were spent in this line (`X` are 3×N cartesian coordinates, `xmin`, `xmax` etc. are vectors of same length as `X` and corresponding boundaries):

```
inlierIdx = ( X(1,:) >= xmin & X(1,:) <= xmax & X(2,:) >= ymin & X(2,:) <= ymax );
```

Could you help me on how to speed this up? Short-circuiting, which would be a good start to improve performance, doesn't seem to work with indexing.

Or if there would be a completely different better approach, here's the rest of the function's code (`p1`, `p2` are the points defining the line, a is the offset of the bounding box; the additional steps took another 12k secs for 55M calls):

```
function [inlierX, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax] = selectbox(X, L, a) % xmin ... ymax only for plotting purposes
% X: 3xN coords to check; L: 3x2 vector defining line; a: offset of bounding box
p1 = L(:,1);
p2 = L(:,2);

constfactor = (X(3,:)-p1(3))/(p2(3)-p1(3)); % precompute for following steps
xmin = p1(1) + (p2(1)-p1(1))*constfactor - a; % line parallel to x-component of defined line, with offset
xmax = xmin + 2*a;
ymin = p1(2) + (p2(2)-p1(2))*constfactor - a;
ymax = ymin + 2*a; 

inlierIdx = ( X(1,:) >= xmin & X(1,:) <= xmax & X(2,:) >= ymin & X(2,:) <= ymax );

if p1(3) == p2(3) % singularity if line is horizontal, discard then
    inlierIdx = [];
end

inlierX = X(:,inlierIdx); % save & return inlier coordinates
```

It just occurred me that I should move that singularity if-clause so the computation is skipped if true, but that's a minor performance hit.

The function is called for each RANSAC sample, to select only points in a reasonable distance from the sampled line to compute their distance for thresholding.

MATLAB version is R2016a.

Parallel Computing Toolbox is available, I tried moving the steps into arrayfuns and calling the whole function with gpuArrays, but it was way slower.

The whole context is as follows:

```
prepare coordinates

while trialcount < expectedNumTrialsNeeded

draw random sample (generated array of randomly sampled coordinates and index into it)

check if sample is not degenerate and has allowed angle

compute number of inliers:

    this calls my selectbox function, to select a smaller set of points, which are near enough to check - takes 30k sec of 55k

    take those points and compute their distance to the line, all points within threshold are inliers - takes 12k secs of 55k

if number of inliers > best number of inliers yet, this is new best set

update expected number of trials needed to find sample of only inliers
increment trialcount

end

return best set
```

I work with arrays of 10k-100k points, and for each line I want to fit I run 1E+5...1E+6 trials to find the best set. I have around 50 lines to fit, I work through them by deleting inliers of found lines and doing the algorithm on the remaining.

Comment: Can you post some more code? The profiler can be a bit misleading sometimes, especially when a loop is not JIT'ed...Also, what version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: @Rody done, thanks for your interest.

Comment: ...More code? Like, is this a function or script? What is calling the function? Is only `inlierX` important, or also `inlierIdx`? Just post a MWE of everything you've got! :)

Comment: @Rody done, check again :)

Comment: Not sure how much of an effect this has, you could check nargout, and if you're only requiring `inlierX` then don't instantiate `xmin` etc. (I'm assuming you don't always plot things).

Comment: @Steve: that seems to have no effect, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that that line is the *real* problem. You say you do 55 million calls to this function -- may we see the code that does that? Because I strongly suspect that *this* code is where the true problem lies.

I suspect that you call this function in a loop, which would make it hard/impossible for MATLAB to accelerate the call effectively with its JIT compiler. If that is the case, then indeed, the heaviest burden shown will be this one line, but it's only so slow because your code structure forces MATLAB to keep calling the interpreter, rather than execute machine code. If this is indeed the case, then copy-pasting this small function in-place in the loop body will tremendously speed everything up (that is, if the remainder of the loop body can also be accelerated...)

Well anyway, this is what I could make of it. It reduces the number of comparisons at the cost of additional indexing; I also doubt that this is faster...oh well, just do 1000 calls and compare.

```
function [inlierX, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax] = selectbox(X, L, a)

    % X: 3xN coords to check; L: 3x2 vector defining line; a: offset of bounding box
    p1 = L(:,1);
    p2 = L(:,2);

    constfactor = (X(3,:)-p1(3)) / (p2(3)-p1(3));

    % line parallel to x-component of defined line, with offset
    xmin = p1(1) + (p2(1)-p1(1))*constfactor - a; 
    xmax = xmin + 2*a;
    ymin = p1(2) + (p2(2)-p1(2))*constfactor - a;
    ymax = ymin + 2*a;

    % singularity if line is horizontal, discard then
    if p1(3) ~= p2(3)        
        inlierIdx            = X(1,:)         >= xmin;        
        inlierIdx(inlierIdx) = X(1,inlierIdx) <= xmax(inlierIdx);
        inlierIdx(inlierIdx) = X(2,inlierIdx) >= ymin(inlierIdx);
        inlierIdx(inlierIdx) = X(2,inlierIdx) <= ymax(inlierIdx);                
    else
        inlierIdx = [];
    end

    inlierX = X(:,inlierIdx); % save & return inlier coordinates

end
```

Comment: Your code was significantly slower, 210s vs 60 in my original. The first boolean operation on the whole array took 5s, the others took ~45, so indexing seems to be the problem.

Comment: @LukasK. have you tried just copy-pasting the function body into the loop body?

Comment: I just tried, and it is phenomenally faster (about 50x speedup). But the weird thing is - it now takes ~1000 trials to find a good solution, instead of the ~500k trials before, and I have no clue why, as I don't think I changed something algorithmically...

Comment: @LukasK. Well, good! you inadvertently fixed a problem you didn't know existed :) In fact, you *did* change something -- you introduced the singularity condition, remember?

Comment: @LukasK.  But this seriously sucks, doesn't it? I was half-hoping that this well-known JIT limitation wasn't the problem, meaning they had **finally** addressed it in R2016...Guess not.

Comment: @LukasK. anyway, remove my junk and replace with your old code, and inline. This fixes the problem, but introduces another -- reduced modularity.

Comment: actually, I left the singularity condition as it was before, just copied all functions into the loop. It's just too good to be true, I have no idea how I now only need 1000 random samples to get a good choice, instead of the 500k before. The rng is always seeded with 1, so I shouldn't get better random numbers or something...

Comment: Yeah, if that's a JIT limitation that's a letdown, though in my case I don't need modularity as it is quite specialized. It's just less readable.

Comment: I found my mistake, a subfunction used the same variable name as its parent, and overwrote it, so it was too optimistic regarding the required number of RANSAC trials. Now that I fixed it, the code using one monolithic function is 1 second faster than the one with functions, for a total runtime of 167s. But as the prematurely terminated results weren't that bad, at least I can investigate my termination criterion. Apart from that, unfortunately my initial question still stands...

Comment: @LukasK. how possible would it be for you to send me all the code and data via e-mail or wetransfer or so, so I can do some testing and profiling a bit easier? I'm curious; the runtimes you mention strike me as rather high for the code you're showing...

Comment: Thank you for your offer (and your general help), but I'm not sure if that's ok, since I'm doing this for a research project as an intern (and my supervisor's gone on holiday so I can't ask right now...)....
The thing is, the code itself is already quite fast, but I'm evaluating combinations of 2 out of 10k...1m points. The 167s amounted to 450k iterations, so each loop iteration had a runtime of ~0.25 ms.

Comment: @LukasK. OK, glad to help. Still I feel I can be useful here, so when he returns and agrees to sharing some toy data set and code, please, let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

What about to use columnwise indexing in your code? I mean to use X as Nx3 cartesian coordinates not as 3xN. As far, as I know columnwise indexing can be faster due to MATLAB arrays are stored in a FORTRAN manner.

Comment: I thought about columnwise indexing, but intuitively I thought that 3xN would be using columnwise indexing as in addressing the individual columns. So it is the other way round and columnwise means indexing within one column?

Comment: While true, the speedup with this sort of thing is usually not phenomenal - think factor of 1.5 or so.

Comment: @RobyOldenhuis Agreed. What is about the linear indexing? Another way I would use in this case is C++ dll or mexfunction.